# I can't compile my classes in Java: xxx cannot be resolved to a type,

Tags: java, class, object, compiler-errors

I'm developing a simple board game in Java, but I'm having some difficulties when trying to instantiate the classes I implemented (Carta, Jogador, and Tabuleiro). When attempting to compile and execute the program, it seems to be unable to find the classes, and I'm getting errors like "Tabuleiro cannot be resolved to a type," for example (the same with Jogador and Carta).

Tabuleiro Class:

Class Tabuleiro:

```
package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Tabuleiro {
    public List<List<Carta>> lines;

    public Tabuleiro() {
        this.lines = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            lines.add(new ArrayList<>());
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Board creation
        Tabuleiro tabuleiro = new Tabuleiro();
```

I'm trying to instantiate the classes this way (the example is only for Tabuleiro), but I'm getting the mentioned error for all classes, which are all in the same directory (src/main).

[image]

Comment: Can you please upload the directory structure? Maybe, the package is wrong.

Comment: Sure, I uploaded it to Google Drive:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WpLFqgJscASWGwduq_NHHkfvJb9HtkQq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello and welcome! I put your Google Drive image in your post, it's easier. See that your IDE complains against your package. What does it say?

Comment: You capitalised the file extensions. Try .java instead of .Java

Comment: Thanks! I still don't know how to add images here, haha. The IDE feedback doesn't say anything specific about the packages, just that it can't find the classes. I'll upload a few more screenshots (now in a folder):

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Yy3la9ZJwZOE3uIqJFPVT5WKpl3pgul_?usp=sharing

Comment: Yeahh, it was the uppercase "J" in the file extension. I made the change, and it worked now! Thank you so much, guys! :)

Comment: You didn't have any trouble 'instantiating objects'. You didn't get that far. You had *compilation errors*. Accuracy please. Always best to cite the actual error message, not what you think it means, or what you were trying to do when you got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the screenshot you've provided it appears that the file names have a `.Java` extension instead of `.java`, hence are not properly recognised as Java source files. Renaming the files with lowercase extensions should do the trick.

As a side note, Java is quite strict regarding naming conventions, e.g., your filename has to match the name of the public class in it, and the directory structure has to match the package name. [See the documentation for more details](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-fileorganization.html).